# Как расположить контент по вертикальному центру страницы

Tags: html, css

Как я могу сделать вот такие отступы по бокам, что бы они уменьшались от размера экрана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: фиксируешь ширину центральной части и ставишь ей margin: auto

Answer (score 3):

Ниже я привел пару самых простых вариантов как это можно сделать:

**margin**

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

div {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

в данном случае все достаточно просто, так как значение `auto` для правой и левой стороны автоматически выровняют целевой блок относительно вертикального центра родителя.

**Flex**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
}

div {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

подробнее про базовые концепты flexbox можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).