# Центрирование div по обеим осям CSS

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при разных разрешениях экрана, блок не двигался с места, а находился по-центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mr+Dafoe&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

.circle {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  margin: 15% auto;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 30%;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Mr Dafoe', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Qwerty</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex), задав для свойства `justify-content` значение "center":

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.circle {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

*Я уже рассматривал данный вопрос более подробно здесь:*

[Как расположить контент по вертикальному центру страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163383/397819)

Comment: я опробовал код, который вы написали, и это  в принципе то, что я хотел. Но при уменьшении разрешения, блок уходит вверх

Comment: @Vasily наверное нужно поправить ещё - border-radius: 100%; на 50%

Comment: @Vasily да, всё верно. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Vasily я не настаиваю, но если следовать вашей логике, то не нужно ничего менять в коде автора

Comment: @Vasily но тем не менее вы изменили на 50%. Если честно, то мой коммент просто был сигнальным (+) Вы очень быстро ответили и вероятно в скопированном коде вопроса просто не заметили эту неточность с  `border-radius: 100%`; Это со всеми бывает и у меня тоже. Не замечаю, пропускаю  ошибки в коде вопроса, если они принципиально не влияют на работу.